# how to get command line arguments within running terminal app

Tags: objective-c, macos

In MAC OS i've created a terminal app through objective C which gets command line argument on the launch through the main function.

Now I need to get additional inputs at the runtime. So how to get them at runtime?
Does the

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run]
```

help achieving this purpose?

Comment: I think you mean you want to read `STDIN`. You can't add/read (cli) arguments at runtime.

Comment: It might help for you to post your `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As Félix Saparelli noted, you're not talking about getting "command-line arguments" in the sense of the arguments passed to your program on the command line, e.g. the `thisfile` in a command such as `cat thisfile`, you're talking about having *your* program accept commands or, at least, accepting input from the terminal, so, as he said, you need to read from the standard input.

`NSRunLoop` won't, by itself, do that for you.  You could just treat your program as a regular UN*X program that just happens to be written in Objective-C, either using standard C library routines such as, for example, `fgets()`, or Foundation classes such as `NSString`, assuming `NSString`'s `stringWithContentsOfFile` method doesn't do something non-useful such as trying to read in the *entire file* and using it as a string, because "read the entire file" is not generally useful when reading the standard input (it will not read a line at a time, it'll just keep reading until you type control-D).